# Nested generics <T1<T2>>

Tags: c#, generics

Why it is impossible to write something like this:

```
T1<T2> Method<T1, T2>(T1<T2> genericValue) { ... }
```

For example, I want to write an extension method which accepts a generic object, containing a generic colletion:

```
Container<CT<T>> ExtensionMethod<CT, T>(Container<CT<T>> value) { ... }
```

where CT can be Array, List or any other collection type and T is any type. But Compiler says "Type parameter T1 does not have type parameters".

Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: `Container<CT<T>> ExtensionMethod<CT, T>(Container<CT<T>> value) where CT : IEnumerable<T> { ... }` ?

Comment: Even if you could do this, how would you get at the contained Objects of Type `T`? If the containers implement a common interface like `ICollection<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` then you should add an extension class for one of those or specify that with a `where` clause.

Comment: @Lithium I tried, but then I need to specify types explicitly, as they cannot be inferred from usage. And it is not very convenient. So I decided to make it generic, too, but it does not compile. So now I am curious, why it doesn't.

Comment: If you want CT to be any type of collection, identify which interface is supported by all the collections you want to be able to use, which also gives the method all the tools it need to do what is intended to do, and use that interface instead of CT.

Comment: What on earth is your use case for such a complex generic? (Genuinely interested)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible. Your generic has to *compile* for *any* `T`. So if you make *any* assumption about `T` other than it being `object` you have to add constraints with the [where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) keyword.

This constraints system is not very complex. You cannot add a constraint asking for `T` to be a class with exactly one generic type parameter. So what you want to do is impossible with the current toolset.

You would need to ask Microsoft *why* they did not implement it, but it appears they saw not enough business value.

Maybe you could ask a question *how* to implement something, without breaking it down to generics. It seems you may have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Though, when you see this for the first time, it is not obvious. And the error it gives, is misleading, I think